# error: invalid command 'build_sphinx'

Tags: python, python-sphinx, rdflib

how can I install the documentation for [rdflib](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib) in mac osx 10.10.1 python 2.7.9? I have followed the instructions as outlined in [1](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib) and I get error: invalid command 'build_sphinx' the documentation does not install. the library rdflib works well, I have tested. also, sphinx is working fine -also tested, which sphinx-quickstart.

Comment: Did you run `python setup.py build_sphinx` or just `build_sphinx`?

Comment: I run setup.py build_sphinx and it gave me the error msg that I reported. my sphinx is properly installed, I tested it

Answer (score 4):

Make sure to have both `sphinx` and `setuptools` installed.

```
pip install sphinx
pip install setuptools
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `setuptools.setup` instead of `distutils.core.setup`

if you replace

```
from distutils.core import setup
```

with

```
from setuptools import setup
```

And you have sphinx installed and setuptools installed...then it will work.